# Oracle Subquery - How to?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables that look like:

```
GL_ROLLUP
Responsibility    Responsibility_L3
15500             15B
15445             15C
15515             15B
15494             15C
15600             15D

GL_Detail
Responsibility    Expense      Amount
15500             6501         30.51
15445             6508         75.60
15515             6535         45.68
15494             6508         65.50
15600             6505         84.39
```

My query right now is pulling the data from the GL_Detail table; however what I want to be able to due is use the search parameter Responsibility_L3 found in GL_ROLLUP so I can query all Responsibilities within this rolled up value (instead of doing a range or a " = '15500' or....."). I tried doing this a few times, but my query seems to get stuck and never brings data back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You are describing a performance problem, not necessarily a query correctness problem. Get familiar with "explain plan", indexes, and other performance tuning approaches. Also, if you show your query that is getting "stuck" we can at least see what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.Responsibility, r.Responsibility_L3, d.Expense, d.Amount
FROM GL_Detail d LEFT JOIN GL_ROLLUP r ON r.Responsibility = d.Responsibility
ORDER BY Responsibility_L3
```

Does that get you what you are looking for?

Comment: You are describing a performance problem, not necessarily a query correctness problem.  Get familiar with "explain plan", indexes, and other performance tuning approaches.  Also, if you show your query that is getting "stuck" we can at least see what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: You commented on an answer, not the question. Just letting you know!

Comment: Thanks this works. I could have sworn when I was playing with this on my own I had similar code, but I must have been missing something.

Comment: Looking at this further I notice that the join is causing the query to duplicate the data - meaning I get 10 or 18 lines of the same transaction. My full code to too long for a comment, but what part of the join could cause the transactions to duplicate?

Comment: Okay I think I answered my own question, I need to use the Group by function. I'll just need to find a column with a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The required query is a simple one:

```
select d.responsibility
       , d.expense
       , d.amount 
from GL_ROLLUP r
     inner join GL_Detail d
           on d.responsibility = r.responsibility
where r.responsibility_l3 = :l3_search_param -- use appropriate notation
```

> "my query seems to get stuck and never brings data back"

If the above query suffers the same fate, that's a performance issue.  You will need to post an explain plan, details of data volumes,indexes, etc